# Will dhcpd give away a fixed-address to non-matching client on address dificit?

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcpd

I have a subnet definition in ISC dhcpd like this:

```
subnet 10.122.224.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    ...
    range 10.122.224.64 10.122.224.127;
    ...
    host room1-printer {
            hardware ethernet 00:26:73:00:4f:33;
            fixed-address 10.122.224.67;
    }
}
```

So the fixed address is within the dynamic range.

What will happen if all addresses from the range except .67 were given away and now one more dynamic client with different MAC-address (not the one specified in hardware ethernet) asks for a lease? Will dhcpd give away this fixed address or reply with DHCPNAK or keep silence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, your right, according to [DHCP server used reserved IP](https://superuser.com/q/932404/264697) and [how dhcpd handles static IPs vs DHCP reservations](https://serverfault.com/q/768655/131555) questions and a thorough reading of the [`man dhcpd.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.conf), using  `fixed-address` directive won't reserve it properly.
This could be done setting directive `infinite-is-reserved` to true and set up your client to ask for an infinite lease (though I don't know how).
The easiest way to achieve would be to have you reservation outside the range of dynamic IP like this:

```
subnet 10.122.224.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    ...
    range 10.122.224.64 10.122.224.127;
   ...
    host room1-printer {
        hardware ethernet 00:26:73:00:4f:33;
        fixed-address 10.122.224.63;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I get it Reseved lease and host stanza are not the same thing. From the same section below: Leases may be set 'reserved' either through OMAPI, or through the 'infinite-is-reserved' configuration option (if this is applicable to your environment and mixture of clients). So this applies to existing lease and is set via different means.

Comment: @demosito well your actually right. My mistake.

Comment: thank you, your links pretty much clear it up. I think this should be accepted answer.